# "This server only speaks WebSocket subprotocols wamp.2"

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, ratchet

I am trying to subscribe to a channel of an api. I tried using 'ratchetphp/Pawl' and Laravel and this is my code:

```
    $loop = Factory::create();
    $connector = new Connector($loop);

    $connector('wss://api.poloniex.com')
        ->then(function(WebSocket $conn) {
            $conn->send('{"event": "subscribe","channel":"ticker","pair": "BTC_ETH"}');

            $conn->on('message', function(MessageInterface $msg) use ($conn) {
                var_dump($msg);
            });
        }, function(\Exception $e) use ($loop) {
            /** hard error */
            echo "Could not connect: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
            $loop->stop();
        });

    $loop->run();
```

However, I am receiving error:

> This server only speaks WebSocket subprotocols wamp.2.cbor.batched, wamp.2.cbor, wamp.2.msgpack.batched, wamp.2.msgpack, wamp.2.json.batched, wamp.2.json

I also tried `$connector('wss://api.poloniex.com', ['wamp'])` and `$connector('wss://api.poloniex.com', ['wamp2'])` but same error persists.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're doing nothing wrong. Ratchet is an older library that doesn't support wamp version 2. https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/168 An alternative that does might be https://github.com/voryx/Thruway